# Django url reverse matching error

Tags: python, django, heroku

This is my application tree :

```
myapp/
  assets/
  statics/
  settings.py
  urls.py
  \\other stuff
main/
  urls.py
  views.py
  templates/
     base.html
     index.html
  \\other stuff
manage.py
```

When testing my application, I have the following error :

```
Error during template rendering

In template /app/main/templates/base.html, error at line 32
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Here is the code in `base.html` involved in the error :

```
{% load i18n %}
\\some stuff

 <a class="brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">{{ site.name }}</a> <--- this line is the error
```

in `main/urls.py` I have :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
)
```

in `myapp/urls.py` I have :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'', include('main.urls'), name='index'),

)
```

Can someone please tell my what I am doing wrong and why the name `'index'` is not reverse matched?

Comment: I don't really know how to do that, I want to put all the mainpage logic inside the "main" folder and all the app configuration inside the "myapp" folder.

Comment: My previous comment was stupid, check out the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` is for single views, it doesn't go with the include statement. Try this way:

in main/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), 
                           name='index'),
)
```

in myapp/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'', include('main.urls')),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser but it gives me a syntax error.


urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
                       url(r'', include('main.urls')),
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       # url(r'', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),                                                                                                                              
)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you only with that info. Is that all you have in `main.urls`? and is that all what the error is saying?

Comment: You might have issues with the regex `r''` Note that when django tries to discover the view by its url, it checks your root `urls.py` from top to bottom. If you add that regex in the middle, it will check first the urls in your `main.urls`. So you might have conflicts with the other url files.

Comment: My intuition is telling me that your error comes from somewhere else though. If `registration.urls` is from django-registration app it won't have any errors, and of course the admin site and `auth.urls` dont have any errors either... so the problem comes from somewhere else in your `main.urls` or some syntax error in your `index.html` template.

Comment: Forget about my comment. The error was in main/urls.py but the error message told me it was in myapp/urls.py. Your anwser worked like a charm. Thank you very much.